# Query returning empty in test - Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to test the following model:

```
class HadoopDistributor(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Some valid clusters are, from the `Django` shell:

```
>>> from clusters.models import *
>>> hadoop_dist = HadoopDistributor.objects.all()
>>> hadoop_dist
[<HadoopDistributor: Cloudera>, <HadoopDistributor: Hortonworks>, <HadoopDistributor: MapR>, <HadoopDistributor: Apache>, <HadoopDistributor: Pivotal>]
```

Now I wrote the following test for the `HadoopDistribution` class:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from clusters.models import *
# Create your tests here.

class ClusterTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.info = { 
                'hadoop_dist': 'Cloudera', 
                'database_repo': 'MySQL', 
                'datafiles': '', 
                'dgsecure': '4.5.2.0', 
                'hadoop_version': '4', 
                'size': '5'
        }

    def test_insert_cluster(self):
        try:
            hadoop_dist = HadoopDistributor.objects.all()
            print hadoop_dist
        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

However, when I execute `python manage.py test` I'm getting:

```
python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
[]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Why am I getting an empty array? The database is `sqlite3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A test database is created when running tests so you won't see data from your production database. That's why the query returns an empty QuerySet. You need to insert new data into your database in the tests if you want queries to return something.

Comment: So I have to inject that info in the setup ?

Comment: Yes, or in a test case, depending on where the data is needed.